# How to remove the attribute style of multiple tags using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my problem...I'm trying to copy the code from below this is the code:

```
    <div class="modalMask" id="ventana_factura_1">
   <div class="modalContent">
      <p style="text-align: right; color: red;" class="mini-1">Folio: 1</span><span>Serie: A</span></p>
      <div style="text-align: right;" class="mini-2">
         <p>Fecha</p>
         <p>2016-01-14</p>
      </div>
      <p class="mini-3">One name</p>
      <p class="mini-4">More data</p>
      <h2 class="mini-5" style="text-align: center; color: #269FE4;">FACTURA</h2>

      <div class="div-table mini-6">
         <div class="div-table-row mini-7">
            <div class="div-table-col mini-8" align="center" style="width: 70px;"><b>Cantidad</b></div>
            <div class="div-table-col mini-9" style="width: 260px;"><b>Descripcion</b></div>
            <div class="div-table-col mini-10" style="width: 100px;"><b>Precio unitario</b></div>
            <div class="div-table-col mini-11" style="width: 110px;"><b>Importe</b></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row mini-12">
         <div class="div-table-col mini-13" style="width: 70px;">5</div>
         <div class="div-table-col mini-14" style="width: 260px;">This is a description</div>
         <div class="div-table-col mini-15" style="width: 100px;">Price</div>
         <div class="div-table-col mini-16" style="width: 110px;">100</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and I'm copying the code with `var factura = $('#ventana_factura_1).html();` and then assign the content to another div `$('#newdiv').html(factura)` and it is working but I would like to remove the attribute style of every tag to just leave in each tag the attribute "class" and its value...something like this:

```
<div class="modalMask" id="ventana_factura_1">
   <div class="modalContent">
      <p class="mini-1">Folio: 1</span><span>Serie: A</span></p>
      <div class="mini-2">
         <p>Fecha</p>
         <p>2016-01-14</p>
      </div>
      <p class="mini-3">One name</p>
      <p class="mini-4">More data</p>
      <h2 class="mini-5">FACTURA</h2>

      <div class="div-table mini-6">
         <div class="div-table-row mini-7">
            <div class="div-table-col mini-8" align="center"><b>Cantidad</b></div>
            <div class="div-table-col mini-9"><b>Descripcion</b></div>
            <div class="div-table-col mini-10"><b>Precio unitario</b></div>
            <div class="div-table-col mini-11"><b>Importe</b></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row mini-12">
         <div class="div-table-col mini-13">5</div>
         <div class="div-table-col mini-14">This is a description</div>
         <div class="div-table-col mini-15">Price</div>
         <div class="div-table-col mini-16">100</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It's this possible? and how could I do this?, thanks.

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga: $('*').attr('style', '') would remove any values from style attribute, not remove it completely.

Comment: To improve on DinoMyte - `$('*').removeAttr('style');`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all attributes of a element based on a whitelist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643248/remove-all-attributes-of-a-element-based-on-a-whitelist)  Whitelist `class` and `align`, remove everything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("*[style]").removeAttr("style");
```

See it live: https://jsfiddle.net/pj7j202e/

This gets any element that has the style attribute, and removes it.
Notice that by using `[style]` in your selector, you select only the ones that actually have the style attribute in them, thus avoiding the elements with no style.

**Edit**: As per @A. Wolff's suggestion, if you just want to get the elements inside your factura, then try this:

```
$("#ventana_factura_1 *[style]").removeAttr("style");
```

Pretty much the same, but it will only target within `ventana_factura_1`'s elements.

Comment: You are targeting them inside all dom, not only relevant container and btw only remove style attribute, not any other one different than class  EDIT: my bad, looks like op wants to keep align attribute even he described the opposite

Comment: Thank you so much, nice explanation

Answer (score 4):

Use `factura.find("*[style]").removeAttr('style')` to remove only in #ventana_factura_1 element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```
$('#newdiv').find("*").removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
factura.find('[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

you can check it works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q11df3js/1/);